# Images in js rotator showing in Chrome and IE but not in Firefox

Tags: javascript, image

I run a site that generates donations for charity and we have just recently launched a new homepage using a js image rotator for our hero image.  We use three images rotating.  It works fine in IE and Chrome but not in Firefox.  It is old code but it works in the others

I have gone through a lot of research but my skills are limited.  I am sure this is something simple that I have overlooked but your assistance would be appreciated.

My code is

```
<div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function initArray() {

this.length = initArray.arguments.length;
for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
this[i] = initArray.arguments[i];
}
}

link = new initArray(
"#",
"http://www.rainbowinitiative.com/about.html",
"#"
);

image = new initArray(
"http://www.rainbowinitiative.com/images/headerimage.jpg",
"http://www.rainbowinitiative.com/images/howitworks.jpg",
"http://www.rainbowinitiative.com/images/3points.jpg"
);

text = new initArray(
"Rainbow Initiative",
"Rainbow Initiative",
"Rainbow Initiative"
);

function getRandom(){
var core = Math.floor(Math.random()*3); // amount of items in array
displayBanner(core)
}

function displayBanner(theNum){
var ranlink = link[theNum];
var ranimage = image[theNum];
var rantext = text[theNum];

//document.write('<a href=/"' +ranlink+ '/" target=/"_blank/"><img src=/"'+ranimage+'/" border="0" 

alt=/"'+rantext+'/"></a>');
document.getElementById('theImg').alt=rantext;
document.getElementById('theImg').src=ranimage;
document.getElementById('theLink').href=ranlink;
}
</script>

<a href="#" target="_blank" id="theLink"><img src="" border="0" alt="" id="theImg"></a>

<script type="text/javascript">
getRandom();
setInterval("getRandom()", 7000);
</script>
```

Comment: Created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g4zv8p5m/) and took a look in FireFox. Not seeing any issues here. What version of FF are you testing? Any plugins that might be causing issues? Any errors in your console?

Comment: Not getting any error msgs at all.  As for the version, I just downloaded the latest version off their site.  35.0.1.  No plug ins being used.

Comment: I put the fiddle on the staging server and I can't get anything to show up.

Comment: Hey Alex, the fiddle is a copy/paste of the code you provided above. I tested in FireFox 36 (Windows) and FireFox 35.0.1 (Mac OS X) and it seems to be working here.

Comment: Is there anything showing up as a 404 in FireFox's Developer Network tab?